# Regex para pegar numeros entre a segunda e terceira "/"

Tags: java, string, regex

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte String /produto/976935/
Como eu faria um regex para me retornar apenas os numeros entre a segunda e terceira barra?
A quantidade de números varia então não adianta retornar apenas os números

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se é sempre produto, você pode fazer:

```
/produto/(\d+)/
```

<sup>[**(regexplained)**](http://tinyurl.com/pkp5uxj)</sup>

Se o prefixo muda a depender do caso use:

```
/(\w+)/(\d+)/
```

<sup>[**(regexplained)**](http://tinyurl.com/p2y9rl7)</sup>

Note que também capturei o prefixo nesse caso.

A depender da linguagem pode ser necessário adicionar escapes nas barras. Troque `/` por `\/`.

Comment: não conhecia esse `regexplained`

Comment: também não conhecia... muito bom ele

Comment: Mas e quando a String for /produto/976935/xxx5.html ? Ele pegaria o 5 também não? Eu preciso de todos os digitos entre a segunda e terceira ocorrencia de barras

Comment: @Mauro não. pegaria apenas o que está entre as barras, seguindo o padrão descrito.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser remover qualquer texto, basta utilizar a expressão a seguir

```
"[^0-9]" ou "[^\\d]"
```

Se for **/produto/976935/** ele vai retornar **976935**, mas se for **/produto/976935/1** ele vai retornar tbm o número 1 e ficaria **9769351**

Em java creio que ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
 var soNumero = soNumero.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

ou

```
 var soNumero = soNumero.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
```